# Alfresco 5.1 have blog posts on site's homepage

Tags: alfresco, blogs

Is there a method to have a blog's posts placed directly on a site homepage section ?
ALex.

Answer (score 1):

I found an interesting collection of add-ons for Alfresco Share from Will Abson (http://share-extras.github.io/) among witch there is a nice site-blog-dashlet to publish blog posts directly on homepage.